# integer and string TCP connection

Tags: java, android, tcp

I actually want to write a TCP communication between a Java Server and my Android game, to save data to a database. Used to have a Global leadboard.

I actually wrote the server right now and can connect to it with a client i wrote and want to implement later in Android.
Here is some code from the Client:

```
    public void saveToDatabase(String name , int level, int killpoints){
        try {
            Socket soc = new Socket("localhost", PORT);
            DataOutputStream  out = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(soc.getInputStream()));

            //to call the save statement!
            out.writeInt(0);
            //give the stuff 

            out.writeUTF(name);
            out.writeInt(level);
            out.writeInt(level);

            //close it
            out.close();
            in.close();
            soc.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What the server now does is it get the first line and checks what to do depending on the value. At the Server this happens:

```
public void run() {
        try {
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream (socket.getOutputStream());
//          DataInputStream  in = new DataInputStream(new InputStreamReader(
//                  socket.getInputStream()));
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            Server.textArea.setText(Server.textArea.getText()+"Client connected: "+ clientNumber+ "\n");

            int firstLine = in.readInt(); //get first line for switch

            switch (firstLine) {
            case 0:
//              getting the whole objekt for the database in own lines!
                String name = in.readUTF();
                int level = in.readInt();
                int kp = in.readInt();
                Server.textArea.setText(Server.textArea.getText() + "SAVE: "
                        + name + " Level: " + level + " KP: " + kp + "\n");
//              Server.textArea.setText(Server.textArea.getText() + "SAVE called\n");       
                break;
            case 1:
                // else if return the top10
                Server.textArea.setText(Server.textArea.getText()
                        + "Return top10\n");
                // outp.write("asdf string");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();
            Server.textArea.setText(Server.textArea.getText()
                    + "Client disconnected: "+ clientNumber + "\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("IO error " + e);
        }
    }
```

I log everything on serverside to a textarea and acutally get this on serverside:
[image: consolebug]

I commit `com.saveToDatabase("test", 2, 123651);`
If i sent everything as UTF i actually get also some strage stuff:[image]

Hope you can help me out or even can tell me if this would work with android too. Thanks alot.
At the moment it does not transfare the string correct.

```
SAVE:  Level: 1908 KP: 1702065249
Client disconnected: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has too many issues.
You write an int (writeInt) but you read a byte (read) on the server.
Also writeUTF puts just a string on the wire but you read a string with a new line.
Use DataInputStream to read the corresponding DataOutputStream.
Also close the output stream before the socket.

Comment: Actuall this was the misstake. I Didn't see that i used differend Input and outputstreams. Changed my code. But still got misstakes with the String now. It's an empty string right now.